# Application to work with KeePass 2 files .KDBX on OS X

Tags: osx, password-manager

What would be a good application that I could use on my Mac to open and edit [KeePass 2](http://keepass.info/) .KDBX files?

I tried running KeePass 2 with [mono](http://keepass.info/help/v2/setup.html#mono), but that is just painful.

What would you recommend?

**EDIT:** Preferably free application

Comment: There's a Macintosh package listed on the KeePass [download](http://keepass.info/download.html) page. Does that not work? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @MichaelKohne Assuming you're talking about [this package](http://keepass2.openix.be/), it requires Mono, which OP stated he'd rather avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried [KeePassX 2.0 Alpha 6 released](http://www.keepassx.org/news/) and it seems to be stable enough to use. Still be careful not to loose any important data.

[image]
[image]

- Supports .kdb format
- Still in development.
- Lots of potential!

P.S. Thanks to @DanteTheEgregore for sharing about KeePassX 2.0

> KeePassX 2.0 is currently in alpha and features .kdbx support. It appears the last version (alpha 5) was released December 5th, 2013. Presumably that's why KeePassX 1.0 hasn't seen updates in quite a while. –  DanteTheEgregore Mar 19 at 1:31

Answer (score 8):

There is MacPass on github:
https://github.com/mstarke/MacPass

It's a native OS X app and it opens my KDBX 2 file just fine, worth a try.

Comment: More details would be good in general but given the question I'd say this is enough although minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [KeePassX](https://www.keepassx.org/downloads/)?

KeePassX is a port of KeePass available on both Linux and OS X, free of charge. KeePassX is licensed under the [GNU General Public License](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt)

[image: KeePassX]

Features:

- native OS X and Linux ports
- Supports .kdb format
- for general KeePass/KeePassX features see [KeePassX Features](https://www.keepassx.org/features/)

Potential Drawbacks:

- KeePassX supports only .kdb and not the newer .kdbx format, however, as per their [faq](https://www.keepassx.org/faq/)

  > you can create an export in KeePass 1.x database format (.kdb) from KeePass 2.x,
  > which KeePassX can read (and use as the native password database).

Comment: "KeePassX supports only .kdb" is exactly why I am looking for something else. Also, the application has not been updated since 2010-03-07...

Comment: @Radi [KeePassX 2.0](https://www.keepassx.org/news) is currently in alpha and features .kdbx support. It appears the last version (alpha 5) was released December 5th, 2013. Presumably that's why KeePassX 1.0 hasn't seen updates in quite a while.

Comment: I did not know there is KeePassX 2. I will check it out and let you know if it works well enough. Thank you for sharing